# android how to display all my facebook friends and invite to play

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-listview, facebook-invite

I am new in Facebook Integration 
In my app i successfully log in through Facebook,

But, I want to,

1. Display all my Facebook friends in list with invite button
2. After Invite invitation sent to them

I much finding but i don't understand Facebook documentation,
So any one please give me any related example,

It very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put some important portion for display facebook friends are followwing. For  more info and any quesry you must refere to,

https://developers.facebook.com/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial

https://github.com/fbsamples/web-friend-smash-v1  and

https://github.com/fbsamples/android-friend-smash-v2

Following main portion for display fb friends list( that have not install game )
To Display Facebook friends on list :

Call following function on your button onClick :

```
      Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
      if (session == null || !session.isOpened()) {
            return;
      }
      List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

      if (!permissions.contains("user_friends")) {

            askForFriendsForPlayPermission(session);

        } else {
            loadFriendsFromFacebook(new FriendsLoadedCallback() {

                @Override
                public void afterFriendsLoaded() {
                    // startGame();
                    close_button_value = 11;
                    img_close_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            });

        }
```

askForFriendsForPlayPermission(...) : this function helps to take friends permission , if you press yes then it show the list of fb friends list, are following:

```
    private void askForFriendsForPlayPermission(final Session session) {
    // user has already said no once this session.
    if (application.hasDeniedFriendPermission()) {
    } else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User hit OK. Request Facebook friends
                        // permission.
                          requestFriendsPermission(AUTH_FRIENDS_PLAY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User hit cancel. Keep track of deny so
                        // that we
                        // only ask once per session
                        // and then just play the game.
                        application.setHasDeniedFriendPermission(true);

                    }
                }).setTitle(R.string.with_friends_dialog_title).setMessage(R.string.with_friends_dialog_message)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Take user_friends Permission - call :

```
    private void requestFriendsPermission(int requestCode) {
    // --//--Log.d("Permiision", "Requesting friends permissions.");
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newFriendsPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this,
            "user_friends").setRequestCode(requestCode);
    Session.getActiveSession().requestNewReadPermissions(newFriendsPermissionsRequest);

}
```

Load facebook friends :

```
   private void loadFriendsFromFacebook(final FriendsLoadedCallback callback) {
   final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
   RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();
   Request invitableFriendsRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "/me/invitable_friends",
            new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Log.e(CricoApplication.TAG, error.toString());
                        // handleError(error, true);
                    } else if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            // Get the result
                            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                            JSONArray dataArray = (JSONArray) graphObject.getProperty("data");

                            List<JSONObject> invitableFriends = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                            if (dataArray.length() > 0) {
                                // Ensure the user has at least one friend
                                // ...
                                // fb_friends = new ArrayList<String>();
                                list_fb_friends = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                                    invitableFriends.add(dataArray.optJSONObject(i));
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject json = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String str_id = json.getString(TAG_ID);
                                        String str_first_name = json.getString(TAG_FIRST_NAME);

                                        JSONObject picture_obj = json.getJSONObject(TAG_PICTURE);
                                        JSONObject data_obj = picture_obj.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);
                                        // String str_is_silhouette =
                                        // data_obj.getString(TAG_IS_SILHOUETTE);
                                        String str_url = data_obj.getString(TAG_URL);

   // put fb id and friends name in map and add to list view 
                                        map_fb_friends = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                        map_fb_friends.put("str_id", str_id);
                                        map_fb_friends.put("str_first_name", str_first_name);
                                        map_fb_friends.put("str_url", str_url);
                                        list_fb_friends.add(map_fb_friends);
                                        fb_friends.add(str_id);

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }


LazyAdapter_fb_friends adapter = new LazyAdapter_fb_friends(HomeActivity.this,
                                        list_fb_friends);
Your_list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }

                            application.setInvitableFriends(invitableFriends);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
    Bundle invitableParams = new Bundle();
    invitableParams.putString("fields", "id,first_name,picture");
    invitableFriendsRequest.setParameters(invitableParams);
    requestBatch.add(invitableFriendsRequest);

    // Get the user's list of friends.
    // This only returns friends who have installed the game.
    Request friendsRequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e(CricoApplication.TAG, error.toString());
                // handleError(error, true);
            } else if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                // Set the friends attribute
                application.setFriends(users);
                callback.afterFriendsLoaded();
            }
        }
    });
```

You can use facebook-id to invite particular friends.

Answer (score 1):

Hope [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends) will help you.
If you want to display all your friends then you have to merge two API

1. The Friends who is not using your app they can be get by calling Graph API invitable_friends [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2) is the documentation for code.
   (invitable_friends can only be get if your FBApp **categorised** as **Games**)
2. The Friends who is already using your app they can be get by calling Graph API friends

Here, if you want to retrieve invitable_friends then you have to [login with permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook#step3).

And the last thing for sending invitation then here is the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2).